# How to install pgAdmin 4 on Fedora 30?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

The RPM given on the [official website](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-rpm/) does not have the `pgadmin4` package for Fedora 30.

Is there a known workaround?

**Edit**: Relevant packages are now included in the RPM, so there is no issue anymore.

Comment: You can use Python wheel for the time being, Ref: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python-wheel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to wait until Devrim gets around to rolling RPMs for Fedora 30.

The alternative is to build the software from source.

**EDIT:** In the meantime, packages for Fedora 30 are available.

Comment: Ok thanks for the confirmation. Might try docker also and will post here if it works out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the link that points to the x64 package:

`sudo dnf -y install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/F-30-x86_64/pgdg-fedora-repo-latest.noarch.rpm`

then you will be able to dnf search and install pgadmin4 normally.

Apparently there is a mistake in the docs for that distro.

Comment: yeah, thanks. It has been solved and relevant packages have been published since I posted the question.